# CSRF Token : unable to use the same token to log in

Tags: php, authentication, curl, post, csrf-token

I'm trying by PHP and cURL to log in a website, but this website use a CSRF token. My PHP code is catching the token (checked with a echo) but I couldn't log in after that (CSRF token error).

Do you have any idea of how I could keep the same cURL session in order to have the same CSRF token (otherwise the server will generate a new one).

I have added comment to my code in order to make it more understandable

Thank you in advance for all your help
Here my code :

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.boursedirect.fr/fr/login";

// obtain the CSRF Token
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie'); // to handle cookies during login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'tmp'); // idem
$headers = [
    'Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100',
    'Connection: keep-alive'
];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$res = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DomDocument();
@ $dom->loadHTML($res);
$elem = $dom->getElementById("bd_auth_login_type__token");
$token = $elem->getAttribute("value"); 
/* extract the token value hidden in <input type="hidden" id="bd_auth_login_type__token" name="bd_auth_login_type[_token]" class="form-control" value="yDVyvTXUhIJjnAj9mTfBO3OKgRpI0zLCUZY2BM_O1E8" /> __ FULLY WORKING */

// second part, trying to log in (same URL)
$username = "X";
$password = "X";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // switching to POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'bd_auth_login_type[login]='.$username.'&bd_auth_login_type[password]='.$password.'&bd_auto_login_type[submit]=&bd_auth_login_type[token]='.$token);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
echo $res; // result is a CSRF token error, so unable to log in

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Get rid of `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` options. Default is to handle them in memory, no need to write to a file. Use `http_build_query()` to create your value for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` – you are doing no escaping here.

Comment: I just changed that through $data = array( "bd_auth_login_type[login]" => "X", etc...); but it's not changing anything. I will follow your cuncils and delete COOKIEJAR / FILE and give you a feedback

Comment: @miken32 thanks for your help and time but again Invalid CSRF Token

Comment: Don't use an array for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, it changes the form submission type to multipart/form-data. Use `http_build_query()`.

Comment: And consider the idea that there might be more things than just CSRF stopping you from an automated login...

Comment: I will use http_build_query, big thanks for your help, and I consider the CSRF just because the page tell me that there is an invalid CSRF token so that's why I think I don't use the latest CSRF Token

Comment: You are submitting wrong post field name also. `bd_auth_login_type[token]` intead of `bd_auth_login_type[_token]`

Comment: @miken32 I added http_build_query and magically it seem to be working because I do not have any login error, I have to thank you a lot for your help. I will upload the working script if any other encounter the same problem. Enjoy a nice end of week, respectfully !

Answer (score 0):

Working script thanks to @miken32 help !

```
<?php
$url = "/";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$headers = [
    'Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100',
    'Connection: keep-alive'
];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$res = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DomDocument();
@ $dom->loadHTML($res);
$elem = $dom->getElementById("bd_auth_login_type__token");
$token = $elem->getAttribute("value"); 

$data = array(
    "bd_auth_login_type[login]" => "X",
    "bd_auth_login_type[password]" => "X",
    "bd_auto_login_type[submit]" => "",
    "bd_auth_login_type[_token]" => $token
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```